# Get dict item without knowing its parent (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I get a dict item without knowing its parent?

Eg.

```
dict = { 
    'parent': {
        'name' : 'example name',
        'version': 99
    }    
}
```

What I want is to get the **version** value, but the **parent** item changes in every request.

I'd like to do some thing like dict[*]['version'], indicating "any value".

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the dict looks like this? `{'foo': {'version': 1}, 'bar': {'version': 2}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a <del>generator</del> list comprehension to get the values if I understand the question correctly:

`versions = [dictionary_name[dict_item]['version'] for dict_item in dictionary_name]`

or

`versions = [dict_value['version'] for dict_value in dictionary_name.values()]`

though I didn't run through a test run to check that it works.

PS: I think you're using the wrong data model for this if that's your usage model.

Comment: Hi, this worked, thanks!

About the data model, this is a JSON response from an application, I just loads it into a dictionary. Just for knowledge, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @jonatas.baldin Searching for specific keys is the only operation really optimized in a dictionary structure so looking for a non-specific key-mapped value is going to be much slower than using some other data structure to keep this data. If you read in the values once but do this search often, consider putting things in a dictionary of `{ name, version}` or storing these in an array as you read them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> versions = [dict[p]['version'] for p in dict]
>>> versions
[100]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like badly designed data model, but this should probably do what you want:

```
{ k:v for level2 in d.itervalues() for k,v in level2.iteritems() }
```

Note that in the case which @senshin mentioned, you will get a randomly chosen value:

```
>>> d = {'foo': {'version': 1}, 'bar': {'version': 2}}
>>> { k:v for level2 in d.itervalues() for k,v in level2.iteritems() }
{'version': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.values()` to enumerate the values of the dictionary, ignoring its keys completely.

```
_dict = { 
    'parent': {
        'name' : 'example name',
        'version': 99
    }    
}

# get the first version you find
for val in _dict.values():
    if val.get('version'):
        print(val['version'])
        break

# get all the versions
versions = [val['version'] for val in _dict.values() if 'version' in val]
print(versions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional list comprehension to get the version of all child elements which have a version key:

```
[dict[key]["version"] for key in dict if "version" in dict[key]
```